# How to mark last row in results of DataTable using R

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I would like to mark (for instance bold) the last row in Data Table generated using DT package. 
Let's say we have a table with the iris dataset:

```
library(DT)
datatable(iris)
```

**Results:** 
[image]

So we have 150 rows and I would like to bold **only 150 row**.

**Edit**:
@BigDataScientist let me clear this. I have this:

```
 output$tbl <- 
    DT::renderDataTable(
      data() %>% # let's say iris data - it doesn't matter
      bind_rows(summarise(data(), SUM = "SUM", A = sum(A), B = sum(B), 
                           C = sum(C), D = sum(D), 
                           E = sum(E), F = sum(F))) %>%
      mutate(SUM = rowSums(.[2:6])),
    extensions = 'Buttons', 
    options = list(
      dom = 'Blfrtip',
      lengthMenu = list(c(-1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25), c('All', '5', '10', '15', '20', '25')),
      buttons = list('copy',
                     list(extend = 'excel',
                          filename = 'report'),
                     list(extend = 'pdf',
                          filename = 'report'),
                     'print'),
     rownames = FALSE,
     server = FALSE
    ) %>%
    formatStyle(
     target = "row",
     fontWeight = styleEqual(dim(.)[1], "bold")
    )
 )
```

So, I would like to add bolding last row; in this case, SUM of columns; to this pipeline, so everything would be in one piece (one pipeline).

Comment: I guess you ask for the last row to be bold, irrespective of the specific value (here 150)?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Answer (score 5):

This [page](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/183) will help you, if you adapt the code a bit:

```
formatStyle(
  datatable(iris), 0, target = "row",
  fontWeight = styleEqual(dim(iris)[1], "bold")
)
```

**Edit:** It was asked (in addition) for the data to be passed as `reactive()` with pipes in Shiny. Well, i can only offer a workaround. I am not that familiar with pipes, especially how to pass several arguments.

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(fluidRow(column(12, DT::dataTableOutput('tbl')))),
  server = function(input, output) {
    irisReact <- reactive(iris)
    dimIrisReact <- reactive(dim(iris)[1])    
    output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(
      irisReact() %>% datatable() %>% formatStyle(
        0, target = "row",
        fontWeight = styleEqual(dimIrisReact(), "bold")
      )
    )
  }
)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted! I only have to test it in my shiny app and I let you know if everything is ok.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't handle with dim function on the reactive object.  I have sth like this: 
_pipeline of reactive data..._
`%>%
    formatStyle(
     target = "row",
     fontWeight = styleEqual(dim(.)[1], "bold")`
but this doesnt work.

Comment: let me take a look, you want  the data variable (here iris) to be reactive, right?

Comment: i also edit my post. I cant help with passing and using multiple inputs with magrittr :(. I could only help with a workaround, see above.

Answer (score 2):

The solution by BigDataScientist failes when disabling rownames in datatable `rownames = F`.

If you want to hide the rownames and have the last row bold, a solution is to anyway set `rownames = T` and then hide them. This works for me:

```
library(DT)

data <- head(iris)

datatable(data, 
          rownames = T, # set rownames T
          options = list(columnDefs = list(list(visible = F, targets = 0)))) %>% # hide the rownames
  formatStyle(0, target = "row",
              fontWeight = styleEqual(dim(data)[1], "bold"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I addition to the answer from BigDataScientist I would also suggest to look at:

http://rstudio.github.io/DT/functions.html