# How to bold last row of reactive expression?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, dt

### Issue:

I'm unable to find a way to subset the reactive expression `table()` in order to bold just the last row.

For background, here is the reactive expression:

```
 table <- reactive({
  filtered <- service[service$test == input$testcenter,]
  filtered[5, (3:8)] <- colSums(filtered[,3:8])
  filtered$expression[5] <- "Net Total"
  filtered
```

})

If I do the following I get the entire table bolded.

```
output$service_table <- DT::renderDataTable(

 if(input$plot.options == "Dollar Amount") {
 table() %>%

 DT::datatable(
      options = list(
           dom = 't',
           digits = 0,
           rownames = FALSE
      )
 ) %>%
 DT::formatCurrency(
      columns = cols,
      currency = "$",
      digits = 0
 ) %>%
 DT::formatRound(
      columns = cols,
      digits = 0
 ) %>%
 DT::formatStyle(
      columns = cols,
      color = DT::styleInterval(0, c('red', 'green'))
 ) %>%
 DT::formatStyle(
      columns = 'metric',#table()$metric,
      valueColumns = 'metric',
      target = 'row',
      fontWeight = 'bold')
})
```

What I would like to do is just have the last row bolded. I have tried all of the following: 
https://www.r-bloggers.com/dt-an-r-interface-to-the-datatables-library/
https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/183
[How to mark last row in results of DataTable using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43253733/how-to-mark-last-row-in-results-of-datatable-using-r/43253996?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

with no success. Any insight on how to properly subset the reactive expression would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it with plain CSS:

```
tbody > tr:last-child { 
  font-weight: bold; 
}
```

*Set the font-weight for the last tr element in tbody to bold.*

```
library(DT)
library(htmltools)
if (interactive()) {
  library(shiny)
  library(DT)
  shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(tags$head(tags$style(HTML("tbody > tr:last-child { 
                                               font-weight: bold; 
                                             }"))), fluidRow(column(12, DTOutput('tbl')))),
    server = function(input, output) {
      output$tbl = renderDT(
        iris, options = list(lengthChange = FALSE)
      )
    }
  )
}
```

[image]

---

If you only want the very last row of your data to be bolded then you could use some JavaScript. Here we hardcode the row number `150` but you could obviously use `nrow(iris)` to find the corresponding cell and row.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(tags$head(tags$style(HTML("tr>td:contains(150)+tr:last-child { 
                                             font-weight: bold; 
}"))), fluidRow(column(12, DTOutput('tbl')))),
  server = function(input, output) {

    jss <- 'function(setting, json) { 
      $("body").on("DOMNodeInserted", "tr", function() {
        if( $(this).find("td").html() == "150") $(this).css("font-weight", "bold");
      });
    }'

    output$tbl = renderDT(iris, options = list(lengthChange = FALSE, 
                                               initComplete = JS(jss)))
  }
)
```